# Word for "scary thing that's about to occur"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have the feeling I'm forgetting a very simple word. But anyway, is there a word for that? Example:

> The [...] that haven't occurred yet are the most scary ones.

Comment: Campaign promises?

Comment: @Hot Licks Scary thing, not untruthful thing.

Comment: Then how about "new version of Windows"?

Comment: *Threats*? *Risks*? *Problems*?

Comment: You can leave the ellipsis, or better yet, a lacuna, which would be really scary, meta-scary, even.

Comment: You could use horrors.  "The horrors that haven't occurred yet are the most scary."

Comment: nightmares, events, things, troubles, tragedies, predictions,

Comment: @Hot Licks It's not scary because I use Linux.

Comment: The *trials* that haven't occurred yet are the scariest?

Comment: Climate change.

Answer (score 3):

Though it doesn't mean “scary thing that's about to occur” I think the word **[scenarios](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scenarios)** fit well in your example: *the [scenarios] that haven't occurred yet are the most scary ones*.

To make it refers to a scary thing you add a describing word like dreadful, frightening and nightmare; *the [nightmare scenarios](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/nightmare%20scenario) that haven't occurred yet are the most scary ones*.

Answer (score 2):

The *[perils](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/peril)* that haven't occurred yet are the most scary ones.

> noun   [MASS NOUN]
>   1.0 Serious and immediate danger:
>
> 1.1 (perils) The risks or difficulties that arise from a particular situation or activity:

Answer (score 2):

There are words you can use to describe scary things, but I do not believe there is a singular word that means "scary thing."  That being said, one word you can use is *dread*:

> **dread**(n): terror or apprehension as to something in the future; great fear. [Dictionary.com]
>
> *Dreadful things* are the most scary ones.

Another is *menacing*:

> **menacing**: something that threatens to cause evil, harm, injury, etc.; a threat [Dictionary.com]
>
> *Menacing things* are the most scary ones.

Another possibility is *impending*, but you would have to use *impending* with another word that implies their scary qualities:

> *Impending awful things* are the most scary ones.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is the word you are looking for, but it's meaning maybe similar.

Foreboding:

noun

1.a prediction; portent.

2.a strong inner feeling or notion of a future misfortune, evil etc.

American Psychological Association (APA):

foreboding. (n.d.). Dictionary.com Unabridged. Retrieved March 25, 2015, from Dictionary.com website: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/foreboding

Answer (score 1):

Catastrophes,  abominations, disasters,  horrors would all seem to fit depending on the context, I like "horrors" best.